# How to Compaire Geolocations In Android?

Tags: android, gps

How to  Compare saved (in database ) Geo Location(Longitude and Latitude)  with currently getting one using GPS.i tried following link but it doesn't work for me ,getting wrong output.Please help me i am new in Android.

[How to use coarse location to compare with saved location in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168545/how-to-use-coarse-location-to-compare-with-saved-location-in-database)

my requirement is exact as explained in ANS.
i did

float radius = 150; // distance in meter

```
  double latitude_new= gps.getLatitude();
  double longitude_new = gps.getLongitude();


  Location location1= new Location("gpslocation");
  location1.setLatitude(21.xxxxxxx);
  location1.setLongitude(78.xxxxxxx);

  Location location2= new Location("gpslocation");
  location2.setLatitude(latitude_new);
  location2.setLongitude(latitude_new);

  float distance = location2.distanceTo(location1);
  distance=Math.abs(distance);
  //comparing two distance and radius

  if (distance <= radius){
      Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "At home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }else {
      Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Not in Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

problem is i m getting only "Not in Home" at SAME location which i have hard-coded and even on other locations(other than hard-coded).

thanks

Comment: so where you stuck at ?

Comment: @DavidJhons-Thanks For Making note of my Que..I have updated my Que so please tell me where am i dong wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provide latitude for the longitude also , edit your code as follows and try ,

```
location2.setLongitude(longitude_new);
```

Comment: @DavidJhons--I tried to Up-vote but it does not allow me as i don't have sufficient Reputation to do so..Really sorry boss